# HttpClient.PostAsync - Why would this throw an ArgumentException

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have other form posts that work fine, but for some reason, this one for throws a "System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range." message.

What could be wrong?

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpMultipartFormDataContent data = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent(about ?? String.Empty), "about");
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent(displayName ?? String.Empty), "name");
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent(email ?? String.Empty), "email");
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent(firstName ?? String.Empty), "firstName");
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent(lastName ?? String.Empty), "lastName");
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent(phone ?? String.Empty), "phone");
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent(isPublic.ToString()), "isPublic");
    data.Add(new HttpStringContent("true"), "isPrimaryProfile");

    Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(uri, data);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, apparently an empty string is not a valid value for HttpStringContent.